# Передача значения в PasswordBox из ViewModel C# WPF MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Здравствуйте! Так как нормального биндинга для PasswordBox не предусмотрено, то пришлось делать биндинг через параметр команды для кнопки. В итоге передача из вью во вьюмодель происходит через метод следующим образом:

ViewModel

```
private void Auth(object parameter)
{
   var passwordBox = parameter as PasswordBox;
   var password = passwordBox.Password;
}

public RelayCommand LoadedCommand
{
     get
     {
         return loadedCommand ??
         (loadedCommand = new RelayCommand(obj =>
         {
            Auth(obj);
         }));
     }
}
```

View

```
<Button Command="{Binding AuthCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=passwordBox}"/>
```

Теперь мне нужно передать какое-либо значение пароля в PasswordBox во вью из вьюмодели, как можно это сделать?

Comment: теоретически вы можете сохранить ссылку на PasswordBox во VM и устанавливать значением там, но как по мне это плохой способ. Другого варианта передавать пароль из VM в V, опираясь на  код, который вы привели, я не вижу

Comment: можно узнать зачем может понадобиться передавать пароль из VM в  V?

Comment: Посмотрите вот эту ссылку: https://habrahabr.ru/post/215249/ Там привязка выполнена по-другому, через свойство VM.

Comment: @foxhound нет, вы что-то путаете - по ссылке добавлено поведение